# ¿Cómo utilizar los elementos de una función en otra función?

Tags: c++, funciones

Necesito su ayuda con el siguiente programa que tiene una función que llama a otra función con el algoritmo de Quick Sort.

```
void Quicksort(int A[], int N);
void Reduce_recursivo(int INI, int FIN);
int main()
{
    int A[]={4,2,6,8,3,5,10,1};
    Quicksort(A,8); //LLamo a la función de la función y paso el arreglo con el numero de elementos...

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
} 

void Quicksort(int A[], int N) //Aqui defino la función
{
    int INI = N-N;
    int FIN = N-1;
    Reduce_recursivo(INI, FIN); //Aqui llamo a la función..
}

void Reduce_recursivo(int INI, int FIN)
{
    int pos, aux, izq, der;
    bool band=true;
    izq=INI; der=FIN; pos=INI;
    while(band==true)
    {
        band=false;
        while((A[pos]<A[der])&&(pos!=der))
        {
            der=der-1;
        }
        if(pos!=izq)
        {
            aux=A[pos];
            A[pos]=A[der];
            A[der]=aux;
            pos=der;
            while(A[pos]>A[izq]&& pos!=izq) //Aquí la función no puede acceder al arreglo. porque? 
          ... //(Sigue más definción de la función)
```

Me sale error y me dice que 'A' no ha sido declarada. ¿Qué debo hacer?
¿Qué me faltaría hacer para que la segunda función pudiera acceder a los elementos del arreglo creado?

Comment: Cuando llames a Reduce_recursivo también debes agregar A como parámetro para poder acceder/modificar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Me sale error y me dice que 'A' no ha sido declarada.

Y es normal, porque `A` no ha sido declarada.

---

En el lenguaje C++, las variables viven dentro de contextos que empiezan al abrir una llave (`{`) y finalizan al cerrarla (`}`), fuera de ese contexto las variables no existen. Para sobrepasar esta limitación, se suelen pasar las variables como parámetro, parece que tú lo tenías planeado pero se te ha olvidado hacerlo:

```
void Quicksort(int A[], int N) // Pasas 'A' como parámetro
{
    int INI = N-N;
    int FIN = N-1;
    Reduce_recursivo(INI, FIN); // No usas 'A' nunca más!
}
```

Posiblemente, tu intención era:

```
void Quicksort(int A[], int N) // Pasas 'A' como parámetro
{
    int INI = N-N;
    int FIN = N-1;
    Reduce_recursivo(A, INI, FIN); // Pasas 'A' a la función.
}
```

Pero para ello, la función `Reduce_recursivo` debería estar preparada para recibir ese parámetro, en lugar de:

```
void Reduce_recursivo(int INI, int FIN)
```

Debería ser

```
void Reduce_recursivo(int A[], int INI, int FIN)
```

#### Posibles mejoras.

Dado que `Quicksort` y `Reduce_recursivo` son casi iguales, podrías eliminar la función `Quicksort` substituyéndola por llamadas de tipo `Reduce_recursivo(N-N, N-1)`, puedes hacer que la función autodetecte el tamaño transformándola en plantilla:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void Reduce_recursivo(int (&A)[N], int INI, int FIN)
```

El parámetro de tipo `int (&)[N]` es una referencia a formación<sup>1</sup> de `N` elementos. Siempre que la función sea llamada con una formación<sup>1</sup> de tamaño prefijado, el parámetro plantilla `N` será autodetectado por el compilador.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu explicación me quedó más claro! Lo probé y funcionó de maravilla!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es declarar la variable `A` fuera de tu función `main` para hacerla variable global.

```
void Reduce_recursivo(int INI, int FIN);
int A[]={4,2,6,8,3,5,10,1};
int main()
{
    Quicksort(A,8);
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
}...
```

Comment: Gracias eso lo resolveria muy bien, lo estoy haciendo tambien en Clases y pensaba hacer lo mismo copiando los valores del Arreglo en un atributo de una class y asi poder usarlos.

Comment: Pero me preguntaba tambien so habria otra manera de hacerlo...

Comment: No. No. No. La solución no es crear una variable global.